# Split de una cadena..shell

Tags: shell-script

Hola que tal tengo la siguiente Cadena de numeros 638283125322
y necesito obtener lo siguiente
6.3.8.2.8.3.1.2.5.3.2.2

Como puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto Gracias

```
    #!/bin/sh
numero=638283125322 
echo ${numero}
total=${#numero}

for (( c=0; c<=$total; c++ ))
do  
   punto+=${numero:$c:1}.
done
salida="${punto:0:${#punto}-2}"
echo ${salida}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilice la función , str_split(numero), ésto le devolverá un array con el númeri dividido uno a uno, y ahí si hace el for para el nuevo array y concatena el punto normal.